# In what time interval is the conditions in a while clause checked?

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, while-loop

How do I wait for a specified time while showing the remaining time to wait?

I now solved it like this but I feel like this is a really bad way to do it:

```
//This is running in a BackgroundWorker:

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
while(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds != SecondsToWait * 1000)
{
    TimeToNextRefresh = ((SecondsToWait * 1000) - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds) / 1000;
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}                   
watch.Stop();
```

So here I am guessing that the condition (`watch.ElapsedMilliseconds != SecondsToWait * 1000`) is checked every millisecond.

So the main question is; In what period is the condition of while checked and/or how do I improve the code I've written?

Comment: Use a Timer object. Writing a hot loop like this is never a good idea. `Thread.Sleep` does not solve any problem.

Comment: @CodyGray could you please provide an example ? I just want to pause execution .... how can I do this with a timer ?

Comment: Why do you want to "pause" execution? Why would that be useful?

Comment: It's not really pause. I am refreshing a DataGrid and want to show the remaining time to the next refresh (CurrentTimeSpan is 1 Minute)

Comment: How you do this depends on what kind of application you're writing. Is this a console app? Windows Forms? WPF? It'd probably help if you told us what's the larger problem you're trying to solve, because as written your code doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Right, so...use a timer. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in this case. Set the timer to tick every 1 minute. When the timer ticks, refresh the control.

Comment: So where do I get the remaining time then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what's the code inside while loop!

For example, if you write some really long/time-consuming code in a while loop, each iteration of the while loop, or course, will be longer than a while loop that only has short/fast code.

Compare these two while loops:

```
while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

and

```
while (true) {
    Console.Beep(5000);
}
```

Each iteration of the first while loop is faster than that of the second one because `Console.Beep(5000)` takes 5 seconds and `Console.WriteLine` only takes a fraction of a second.

So you can't rely on while loops to count time.

This is what you should do:

Create an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, **not** the `System.Timers.Timer` **nor** the `System.Threading.Timer`. I find the first one the most useful (others are more advanced).

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 means 1000ms aka 1 second
timer.Tick += TimerTicked;
timer.Start();
```

Now the compiler will tell you that `TimerTicked` is not defined, so let's go define that:

```
private void TimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Now you're all set. The code in `TimerTicked` will be called every one second.

Let's say you want to measure a time of 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, you want to do something. So first create a variable called `secondsLeft` in the class level:

```
int secondsLeft = 10;
```

Now in `TimerTicked`, you want to check whether `secondsLeft` is 0. If it is, do that something, else, minus one:

```
if (secondsLeft == 0) {
    DoSomething();
} else {
    secondsLeft--;
}
```

And `secondsLeft` *is* the time remaining! You can display it on a label or something.

To pause the timer, simply

```
timer.Stop();
```

Comment: What is wrong with `Timers.Timer`/`Threading.Timer`? It sounds like you don't recommend it. You could just write `var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();` to clearly show which one you choose without introducing said ambiguity. Btw, winforms in wpf is ... [kek](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kek).

Comment: When I first saw these three timers, as a beginner, I found the winforms one the most intuitive to use. Threading timer is really... nasty... I tried `Timers.Timer` but it doesn't (seem to) run the event handler on the UI thread. That's why I didn't like it. And I didn't know that OP is dealing with WPF when I am writing this answer. Even if I knew, I would still post the answer because OP seems like a beginner. I think the winforms timer is the most suitable for beginners because of its intuitiveness. I mean, OP can try out others when he has more experience. @Sinatr

Comment: Yes, in WinForms applications, you should use the WinForms timer. The other timers are all designed for different purposes. It is not intuitive because it is better designed, it is intuitive because it is designed to work from a WinForms application. If you have a console app, using the WinForms timer won't be intuitive; in fact, it won't even work at all.

Answer (score 2):

The exact interval in which your `while` condition is checked is hard to predict. `Thread.Sleep(1);` only tells the operating system that you want your thread to sleep for *at least* 1 millisecond. There is no guarantee that your thread will be active again after exactly 1ms. Actually you can rather be sure that it will be more than that. The thread is scheduled again after 1ms, but there will be a delay until he gets his CPU time slot.

The interval you *want* for your loop actually depends how you want to display the remaining time. If you want to display only seconds, why would you update that display every millisecond, although the text would change only every 1000ms?

A loop like that is probably not a good way to implement something like that. I would recommend a `System.Threading.Timer`:

```
// this Timer will call TimerTick every 1000ms
Timer timer = new Timer(TimerTick, null, 0, 1000);
```

and implement the handler

```
public void TimerTick(object sender)
{
    // update your display
}
```

Note that you will have the "update your display" part on the UI thread again, as this method is called by the `Timer` on a different thread.

Comment: I am using WPF and I want to refresh a DataGrid (so every minute I get some data from sql). When I got the data I restart the Worker in the CompletedEvent and want to show the time remaining till the next refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I feel sorry for asking so many questions but is there a buildin way to get the remaining time to the next tick ?

Comment: @Nudity Why would you want that? This `Timer_Tick` is now called every 1000ms (so once every second). The logic to calculate the time until you get your next update is up to you as I don't know your project/code. Though this method may also not be called _exactly_ every 1000ms (but some nanoseconds later), it's exact enough to display seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This code is can really make an infinite loop if a calculation just take longer than 1 miliseconds.

You can achieve your desired behaviour with a simple System.Winforms.Forms.Timer  like this snipped below :

```
    private int tickCount = 0;
    private int remaining = 10;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remaining--;
        textBox1.Text = remaining.ToString();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

With this you can countdown from 10 seconds and every tick you write to a textbox the remaining seconds